# JSON Object complex example get localId in users object

Tags: json, react-native, expo

{
"kind": "identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse",
"users": [
{
"localId": "XR9iEJd8SpWLZyIlTclB77lquz52",
"email": "abdulrehmansnp57@gmail.com",
"passwordHash": "UkVEQUNURUQ=",
"emailVerified": false,
"passwordUpdatedAt": 1666284051842,
"providerUserInfo": [
{
"providerId": "password",
"federatedId": "abdulrehmansnp57@gmail.com",
"email": "abdulrehmansnp57@gmail.com",
"rawId": "abdulrehmansnp57@gmail.com"
}
],
"validSince": "1666284051",
"lastLoginAt": "1666346094257",
"createdAt": "1666284051842",
"lastRefreshAt": "2022-10-21T09:54:54.257Z"
}
]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to return the "**localId**", but since it's an array I will assume you will have multiple users. So here's an example of how you can return an array of the "**localId**" in react or JavaScript in general:

```
const obj= { "kind": "identitytoolkit#GetAccountInfoResponse", "users": [ { "localId": "XR9iEJd8SpWLZyIlTclB77lquz52", "email": "abdulrehmansnp57@gmail.com", "passwordHash": "UkVEQUNURUQ=", "emailVerified": false, "passwordUpdatedAt": 1666284051842, "providerUserInfo": [ { "providerId": "password", "federatedId": "abdulrehmansnp57@gmail.com", "email": "abdulrehmansnp57@gmail.com", "rawId": "abdulrehmansnp57@gmail.com" } ], "validSince": "1666284051", "lastLoginAt": "1666346094257", "createdAt": "1666284051842", "lastRefreshAt": "2022-10-21T09:54:54.257Z" } ] };

const ids= obj.users.map((e)=>e.localId);
```

response: ids=[XR9iEJd8SpWLZyIlTclB77lquz52];